# How many different possible combinations are in the Fifteen (15) Puzzle? How to calculate it?

Tags: probability

How many are there and how to calculate it? I thought there are: $15 \times 16 \times 15$ but it's probably wrong! Please somebody tell me!

Comment: Why do you think it is $15\times 16\times 15$?

Comment: The number that you suggest is *way* too small.  If each number (including the blank) could be in any position, could you find the number of possible permutations?

Comment: Where did you get your $15\times16\times15$ figure from?  Why do you need to know?  And are you looking for the number of _reachable_ configurations, or the total number of ways of putting the tiles in the grid?

Answer (score 1):

If you just think of placing the blocks into the frame, including the blank, it is just like lining up $16$ items in a row, which is $16!$.  You pick one item for the first slot ($16$ choices) one of the remaining $15$ for the next, and so on.  Then if you want to be able to slide there from the original position, you can only get to half the positions, as [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle), so by sliding you can get to $\frac 12\cdot 16! \approx 10^{13}$ positions

Comment: Wait,does that mean that this simple puzzle has more possible combinations than a 2x2x2 Rubik's cube? (Also known as Pocket cube,which has 3674160 p. c.)

Comment: Sure, a $2 \times 2 \times 2$ Rubik's cube has only eight pieces.  If we allow arbitrary rotations of each cube, there are $3^8\cdot 8!=264539520$ postions.  I think only $\frac 16$ of these are reachable, which would give $44089920$ reachable positions.  Factorials grow very quickly, making the exclamation point an appropriate symbol.  The value you quote considers rotations of the cube to be the same, while mine considers them different.  There is a factor $12$ between them.